# How to show a View with Rules

Tags: 7, views, rules, userpoints

I want to add an action that shows a view whenever the user earns [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints). I checked it and there's no rules for [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) so I'm wondering how could I do it.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the path to the view you want to show is "`SomePath`". Then just create a rule with a Rules Action to "perform a redirect", to the path `SomePath`.

For a rule with such Rules Action, you just use whatever Rules Event that fits your needs (something related to user points I assume), and optionally add whatever Rules Conditions that fit. For a rule that you can probably use as a good starting point, have a look at my answer to "[How to change user info with a rule when Points are granted to user (using userpoints module)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55094/how-to-change-user-info-with-a-rule-when-points-are-granted-to-user-using-userp/219235#219235)" (if you'd just add a Rules Action to redirect, you may be close already).